# yii2 проблема в ActiveRecord с joinWith + limit

Tags: yii2, activerecord

у меня запрос `Product::find()->joinWith('sizes')->all();` - 9 строк

запрос `Product::find()->joinWith('sizes')->limit(6)->all();` - 3 строки

не могу понять почему во втором случае не правильно limit считается

Comment: если `Product::find()->joinWith('sizes')->distinct('id')->limit(6)->all();` - 6 строк как нужно, но по непонятной мне причине

Comment: проверьте сам sql запрос, который выполняется, дело не в limit, а в joinWith - который вероятно INNER JOIN - что может сократить кол-во рядов в ответе.

Comment: используется LEFT JOIN. все разобрался как лимит рядов считается. в ряду один продукт но разные размеры (в моем случае получилось 4 ряда с одним продуктом, но разными размерами), поэтому и distinct по id продукта спасает, а таблицу размеров подключал чтоб потом по ним и другим столбцам продуктов фильтровать выборку.